# ANTLR4 - generating java code into csharp output

Tags: antlr4

Using antlr4 (4.11.1) code generation tool to generate csharp code the tool is generating a single line of java in the grammar c# file (there are plenty of c# lines of code)

`

```
throw new RuntimeException("UNEXPECTED_CHAR=" + (_localctx._UNEXPECTED_CHAR!=null?_localctx._UNEXPECTED_CHAR.Text:null));
```

`
which confuses the .net compiler.

Its simple enough to remove, but how did it get there?

Generated csharp code from grammar/lexer using the generation tool using

`antlr4 -Dlanguage=CSharp ./grammar/sql/sqlGrammar.g4 ./grammar/sql/sql_lexer.g4  -no-visitor`

And expected valid c# to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

The code `throw new RuntimeException("UNEXPECTED_CHAR=" + (_localctx._UNEXPECTED_CHAR!=null?_localctx._UNEXPECTED_CHAR.Text:null));` will be in either `sqlGrammar.g4` or `sql_lexer.g4`.